# What is the distance needed between a linear actuator and the hinged solar panel?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]   I am making a solar panel that can be lifted by a linear actuator below it, the image represents well my idea, but still can't calculate how far the linear actuator needs to be from the hinged point of the solar panel. I know my actuator has a force of 1500 newtons, so I wanted the math and formulas to calculate the distance between those points, where I can make the solar panel have a rotation of about 80 degrees, max of more less 80 and minimum of a 0 degrees compared to the ground, but still be able to lift it with 1500 newtons of force. I know that the formula for the push force of the actuator on this case is F = 2mg/tan(angle of actuator and floor)-tan(angle of solar panel hinged point).

Comment: Please use [math formatting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) for the equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a free body diagram describing all the forces acting, as a function of the tilt of the panel, $\theta$. You also need to describe where the center of mass is, as well as the location of where there forces act.

[image: fig]

Suppose you know the distances $a$ and $b$ above, when the panel is flat the actual is going to be at distance $a+b$ from the pivot. In this configuration no amount of force will lift the panel unless the actuator force $F$ is *above* the pivot.

In general, with the tilt angle $\theta$, the actuator will displace an amount $$x =a + b - a \cos \theta - \sqrt{b^2-a^2 \sin^2 \theta} \tag{1}$$

Now the little stand that pushes up on the panel is a two force member (no side loading) which means the combined load of $F$ and $B_{\rm y}$ run along its length. Or, the pin that pushes the panel up is zero torque applied from the stand.

This happens when

$$ \frac{ B_{\rm y}}{F} = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{a}{b} \sin \theta \right) 
 \tag{2} $$

Now the force balance equations are

$$ \begin{array}{c} A_{\rm x} -F = 0 \\ A_{\rm y} + B_{\rm y} - m g = 0 \end{array} \tag{3}$$

and the torque balance at the pivot is

$$ (a+b-x) B_{\rm y} - \tfrac{L}{2} m g \cos \theta = 0 \tag{4}$$

All of the above equations (4 equations and 4 unknowns) yield the actuator force required

$$ \boxed{ F = \tfrac{L}{2} m g \frac{ \cos \theta \sqrt{b^2-a^2 \sin^2 \theta}}{a ( a+b-x) \sin \theta} } \tag{5} $$

Note that peak load occurs when at the minimum angle where the mechanism rests.

You can approximate the force at small angles as

$$ F \approx \tfrac{L}{2} \frac{b \,m g}{a(a+b) \sin \theta} $$

Use the above to find the combination of $a$, $b$ and $\theta$ that matches your actuator.

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: What does L means on the last equation ?

Comment: $L$ is the length of the panel, where gravity is acting on $L/2$ distance from pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if the actuator is laying flat, it cannot lift the panel.  You need to choose some reasonable minimum (and maximum) angle for the panel and then start your calculations from there.